# How can I register a winservice?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

How can I register a windows service within c#.net?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208575/how-do-you-register-a-windows-service-during-installation

Comment: i want to do that at runtime.
and i want to know if service is registered before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ([Easiest language to create a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-to-create-a-windows-service/593803#593803)) is a step-by-step set of instructions for creating a Windows service in C#.  Steps 6-9 show how to prepare your service to be registered with the local machine.  Step 9 discusses how to use `InstallUtil.exe` to install your service.

To take it a step further, you can refer to the step-by-step instructions here ([How to make a .NET Windows Service start right after the installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195478/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-start-right-after-the-installation/1195621#1195621)) in order to have your Windows service install itself from the command line, i.e., without having to use `InstallUtil.exe`.  For example, to install the service, you'd use this

```
MyService.exe /install
```

To uninstall, you'd do this

```
MyService.exe /uninstall
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these

- [Creating a Basic Windows Service in
  C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WindowsService.aspx)
- [Creating a Windows Service with C#](http://devhood.com/Tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=300)
- [Creating a Windows Service in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/window_service11262005045007AM/window_service.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To find out if the service is already installed, get the list of services that are installed, and see if yours is in it:

```
bool existsAlready = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices()
  .Where(service => service.ServiceName == yourServiceName)
  .Any();
```

To actually install it, you have to create an installer object and tell it your executable and service name. Something like:

```
ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller 
{
  Account = ServiceAccount.LocalService
};
string executablePath = String.Format("/assemblypath={0}", "yourprogram.exe"));
InstallContext context = new InstallContext(null, new[] { executablePath });
var installer = new ServiceInstaller
{
 Context = context,
 DisplayName = yourServiceName,
 Description = yourServiceName,
 ServiceName = yourServiceName,
 StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic,
 Parent = serviceProcessInstaller,
};
installer.Install(new System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary());
```

This is more or less all that InstallUtil.exe would do with your classes if you did it the documented way.

To start or stop a service, use the ServiceController class.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Writting Windows Service](http://dotnetatwork.blogspot.com/2009_06_01_archive.html)

Answer (score 0):

[How do you register a Windows Service during installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208575/how-do-you-register-a-windows-service-during-installation) question tells us about this great step-by-step tutorial:

[Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. It depends on the context:

1) You can create a Windows Installer package to do this for production. I believe a Visual Studio setup project will do this.

2) For development, installutil.exe should do it, as **Svetlozar Angelov** already said.

3) If you really need to customise the installation somehow you can write your own .NET code to do it. Look at the `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller` class.